# Splitting product of $\gamma$-matrices into symmetric and anti-symmetric part

Tags: symbolic, tensors

The [$\gamma$-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) satisfy the relation
$$\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu +\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathrm{id},$$
where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric. Consider now the following process
$$\begin{align*}
\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu 
&= \frac{1}{2!}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu +\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)
= \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu + (2\eta^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu))\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu)+\eta^ {\mu\nu}\\
&=:\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu}+\eta^{\mu\nu}.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
One can now repeat this process and obtain
$$\begin{align*}
\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\sigma &= \frac{1}{6}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma}+ \eta^{\mu\nu}\gamma^\sigma- \eta^{\mu\sigma}\gamma^\nu+\dots
\end{align*}$$
where $\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma}$ is the anti-symmetrization of $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\sigma$.

Is it possible to obtain this result in Mathematica for an arbitrary product of $\gamma$-matrices, i.e.
$$\gamma^{\mu_1}\dots \gamma^{\mu_r}\qquad \text{for }r\in\mathbb{N}?$$
(Realisticly speaking, I only need it for $r<8$.)

**Edit:**
It's probably worth pointing out that one can create the antisymmetric part quite easily using

```
Symmetrize[\[Epsilon], Antisymmetric[{1,...,r}]]
```

Comment: I would like to state that this is an important question and the answer is relevant to my research (any QFT researcher would be interested in this I think).

Answer (score 1):

One should realize that the gamma matrices are just a (3,1)-dim representation of a geometric algebra. This means we associate the gamma matrices with noncommutative basis vectors.

So you could use the following geometry algebra package:

github.com/ArturasAcus/GeometricAlgebra
The wedge operation here is implemented as OuterProduct. No operations without basis vectors, no differentiation.

Code to work with a (3,1)-dim representation of a geometric algebra

```
gaDefineOrthonormalBasis[Cl[3, 1], FontColor -> Red]
gaRunningAlgebra
```

Now the questions you asked can be simply computed. Question 1:

```
GeometricProduct[\[DoubleStruckE][1], \[DoubleStruckE][2]]
GeometricProduct[\[DoubleStruckE][4], \[DoubleStruckE][4]]
```

Question 2:

```
GeometricProduct[\[DoubleStruckE][1], \[DoubleStruckE][
2], \[DoubleStruckE][3]]
```

I guess you could also define a function named gamma (this may not be the best way to do it, but just as an example)

```
Clear[f]; \[Gamma][i_] := \[DoubleStruckE][i]
g[i_, j_] := GeometricProduct[\[Gamma][i], \[Gamma][j]]
g[1, 2]
g[1, 1]
g[4, 4]
```

Comment: You could also code this yourself of course, using the code here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249670/what-is-the-best-source-to-learn-how-to-use-tensor-operations-exterior-algebra look at the answer by xzczd, but that will take some serious work in order to create a fast properly working program